# Trying to use .filter() to search by an Integer value

Tags: javascript, json

With the following Json object, I am using `.filter()` to search for one object.

It seems I can select by a string type, for example:

`this.devices.filter( (dev) => { return dev.Device.DisplayName == "Test Again" } );`

However, trying to select by the Integer type does not work (it just returns all records):

`this.devices.filter( (dev) => { return dev.Device.UID == 2 } );`

```js
[{
    "InstanceID": 11,
    "Device": {
        "UID": 1,
        "DisplayName": "Test123",
        "DeviceHostName": "",
        "Location": null
    },
    "HostService": null
},
{
    "InstanceID": 22,
    "Device": {
        "UID": 2,
        "DisplayName": "Test Again",
        "DeviceHostName": "",
        "Location": null
    },
    "HostService": null
},
{
    "InstanceID": 33,
    "Device": {
        "UID": 3,
        "DisplayName": "Test Yet again",
        "DeviceHostName": "",
        "Location": null
    },
    "HostService": null
}]
```

Again, I would like to .filter() by the `UID` property and simply return that object.

thanks.

Comment: This should work as well, there is no reasonable explanation why it wouldn't. I just run your code and it produces exactly the result you want.

Comment: If you try the exact functions you show here, on the exact data you show here, you will find that it works exactly as you expect.

Comment: it could be I'm selecting the wrong fields form the source data...checking now....thank you.

Comment: A word of caution. Use `===` for all comparisons, except you explicitly, positively *want* type conversion to happen.

Comment: The only thing I notice is that you don't have an array `[...]` enclosing those three objects, which I had to add to test it `let devices = [ {...} ...];` but I assume your real code has that, or your filter with a string wouldn't work.

Comment: @StephenP - indeed my code did have the brackets (now reflected in my post), thank you. @Tomalak - agreed that I should use explicit `===`